# site appears in Google Webmaster Tools but no site: search results

Tags: google, google-search-console, wordpress, google-index, meta-tags

My site is geocology.ca.

About a year ago I attempted to add geocology.ca to Google's search index by following the steps for 'Moving Your Site' in Google's Webmaster Tools, transferring from my old site at hughstimson.com.

Everything seemed to go fine.

- I submitted a sitemap for the new site, and it was read successfully.
- I added a robots.txt file with a single entry ALLOWing all user
  agents, and it quickly showed up in Webmaster Tools, properly
  registered.
- When I go to Google Webmaster tools there are no errors
  and no complaints.

**BUT**: my site never appeared in Google's search results. At all. Searching for [site:geocology.ca](https://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3ageocology.ca) produced no results.

After a couple of months I added a [small wordpress blog](http://geocology.ca/happy/) in a sub-domain, as a sandbox for a client. That blog quickly showed up in Google's index, and now if you search for site:geocology.ca the content of that (fake) blog is all that will appear.

Does anyone know how I can address this? Is there perhaps a way to completely reset Google's knowledge about my site and start again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not indexing because you're instructing not too...

**Remove this from your pages:**

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
```

**Fix this in WordPress:**

1. Login to Administration Dashboard
2. Click Settings > Privacy > (Ensure that indexing is allowed,If WordPress is set to have search engines index the site, then check your theme's header.php)

Comment: Thank you, that resolved it. `Settings > Privacy` wasn't present in my Wordpress admin, but `Settings > reading > Discourage search engines from indexing this site` was checked for some reason. Unchecking it removed the meta tag. The site hasn't appeared in Google yet, but I trust it will now.

Comment: give it 1-2 weeks and bam! posting something in the blog may speed up the process.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for letting us how you got on.. ;)